# Changing URL and retaining values on dropdown onChange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I have created a Magento site that has Japanese and English store. For both of these stores, I have almost the same products. I just added additional attributes to add the english texts where necessary such as the name. So for example, in my Japanese store, the product's name is "靴" then in English store it's "Shoes". Given this, I have to make adjustments to my url and breadcrumbs to accommodate both languages.

Anyway, I added a currency selector for my English store which works perfectly. The only problem I'm having with it is that it reloads my page completely and the changes I made in the url and breadcrumbs disappear and goes back to default. My url and breadcrumbs should look like this in the English store:

```
url: http://mywebsite.com/mycategory/shoes.html?cat=mycategory&prod=shoes
breadcrumbs: Home > My Category > Shoes
```

But whenever I try to change the currency, it reloads my page and I end up with this url and breadcrumb:

```
url: http://mywebsite.com/mycategory/shoes.html
breadcrumbs: Home > My Category > 靴
```

The code for my currency dropdown looks like so:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$root = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

//UPDATE:
$currency = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('currency');
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
//if I try to echo these two, it both returns the correct current currency

$cats = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $root);     
foreach($cats as $_cat):
    $cat_name = $_cat->getName();
endforeach;

//UPDATE:
$productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl."?cat=".urlencode($cat_name)."&prodname=".urlencode($_product->getName_en());

if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<label for="custom-currency-selector"><?php echo $this->__('Select Currency:') ?></label>

//UPDATE: changed window.location.href to setLocation
<select onchange="setLocation('<?php echo $productUrl ?>' + '&currency=' + this.value") name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>

  //UPDATE: option value
  //if I echo $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode(), its value is different from the current. It returns the previously selected currency
  <option value="<?php echo $_code; ?>"
        <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
            selected="SELECTED"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $_code ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried changing the onchange event value to window.location.href=this.value+'' but that isn't working at all. My url is not retained. So my question is, how can I change the currency while retaining the changes I created for my url and breadcrumbs?

Update:
As per Natalie's suggestion, I've changed $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) to simply $_code and made some more change to my currency.phtml to accommodate my needs. I am now able to retain my url params and change the currency. The problem now is that even though I am able to set the currency programmatically, the select option and currency would not change immediately. For example if my current currency is $ and I try to change to JPY, what happens is it remains $ then for the second time, I select EUR, JPY currency is used instead then the next currency used would be EUR. Basically, my code seems to get the previously selected currency instead of the current one. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Magentos default language/store switcher? If you do, have you created different category names for the Japanese and the English store view? Because then this shouldn't be an issue, magento will save the language/store choice in cookie and then show the categories connected to that store.

**Edit**: I'm going to add this here instead because a comment is too short:

Sorry. I missed that you hade trouble with adding the params to the original value. You could do what I did when I wanted to change store view and currency on the same button click.

You can set the currency manually yourself instead. If you change the value of the currency dropdown to only contain the currency code like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $_code?>" ...
```

And instead of going to `this.value` go to the following url on change

```
onchange="setLocation('?cat=mycategory&prod=shoes&currency='+this.value)"
```

At the top of your header.phtml file add the following to get the currency param and set the new currency.

```
if($currency = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('currency')){
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
}
```

I haven't tested this exact code so I can't guarantee it will work perfectly. But I have myself done a version of it that works great.

Comment: Actually, I used 2 different websites for each language. My boss didn't want the store switcher and wanted to use different urls for both so I had to recreate the japanese website in english. Anyway, I am using 2 different categories for each language but they have the same inventory and same products.

Comment: Okay, I see.
Im guessing that it's the params in the URL you want to keep.
You could add the params at the currency change like this: `window.location.href=this.value+"?cat=mycategory&prod=shoes"`. **Or** you could get the params from a cookie. If I'm not mistaken Magento will save the params in a cookie after they're sent for the first time. You could then get this cookie at every page load and print the correct category that way.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot, I'm able to retain the URL params now but this.value's value is a link so my URL now looks something like: http://mywebsite.com/myshop/myproduct.html?cat=mycategory&prod=shoes&currency=http://someurl. Is there any way I can get rid of that in my url while still retaining the selected value?

Comment: Hey. Sorry I missed editing the option string. To just get the value change `$this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)` to just `$_code`, see edited post above

Comment: But then that would prevent the website from changing currencies. Actually, I'm not sure if I destroyed something or wasn't working in the first place but the code I've updated as working earlier doesn't work now. It retains the url but the currency did not change

Comment: Not if you get the currency param later on and manually set the current currency code with `Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);` I updated my original post as well, the onchange for the select box should be 'onchange="setLocation('?currency='+this.value)"'. I tried this myself and it worked.

Comment: really? that's strange then. Whenever I add that code, my phtml file either gets broken or it just adds the code on my breadcrumbs and it doesn't change the currency. Anyway, I'll give it another shot. Thanks.

Comment: You're right after all. It apparently works, the current problem is, my page gets the previously selected currency instead of the one you select currently. so it's not working properly

Comment: That's odd. Are you getting the correct currency when you get the parameter?

Comment: Yes, it gets the correct parameter. Actually, I tried to echo the current currency and it gets the correct one as well but strangely, the select element does not get it and the prices don't get converted immediately. I'm updating my original post to show how my code looks now

Comment: Hm, It might be a timing issue seeing as you probably need to set the new currency before the prices etc are loaded. Where in your page is the currency dropdown loaded? Try moving the code where you get the params to the top of your header.phtml file instead.

Comment: I've placed it on my product page as per requested

Comment: Okay, but where in your product page is it loaded?
Did you try adding it to the header.phtml file as I suggested?

Comment: In view.phtml. It used to be in my header file but the client asked it be put specifically in the product page. Anyway, I guess I'll just go to the 2nd route of using cookies. I'm almost done with it anyway. I'm just stuck with trying to replace/delete the cookies when it leaves the page.

Comment: Just to specify what I meant. I only meant you should get the currency parameter in the header.phtml file. The rest of the code can be as it is now.
To delete a cookie use `Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->delete($name)` .
[link](http://apptha.com/blog/how-to-set-get-and-delete-cookies-variables-in-magento/) great article about how to use cookies in magento.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you meant. Do you mean replacing $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode inside the option value? As for the cookies, I can delete the cookies no problem. I'm just having problems with when I should delete it and stuff. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Never mind. I was right, I didn't understand your original suggestion very well. Anyway, I placed the setCurrencyCode part in the header.phtml file and it seems to work. I'll try adding the modifications on our actual server and fingers crossed it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to be at help :) If you get it to work I would appreciate if you if you marked my anwer as accepted :)